# jQuery toggle next ul li based on the icon click

Tags: jquery, html, css

Trying to do accordion style display.

Better reference to the kind of display I want:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/SPHAS.jpg

You will notice to the right of Lily there is an arrow, clicking on it should show the items under.

My challenge is in traversing through the DOM correctly to locate the next ul to show/hide when button is clicked. How I do that?

As I'm sure you can tell what I'm trying to do is show the nested style but in a box to create an accordion effect.

Working fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/zigzag/aLb5d2uL/10/

```js
$('.menu-toggle').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); // prevent <a> to redirect to the top of the page
  $(this).nextall('ul').toggle();
});
```

```css
.chartArea {
  padding: 20px 20px 0 0;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.glyphicon {
  color: white;
}

.tile {
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: gray;
  font-family: segoe UI;
  color: white;
  min-height: 150px;
}

.empDetails {
  font-size: 14px;
  color: white;
}

.chartArea ul li {
  display: none;
}

.chartArea>ul>li {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid chartArea">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <div class="tile">Adam</div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="tile">
        <div class="col-sm-2 img_tile">
          <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x50">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-8 empDetails">
          <h4>
            Lily
          </h4>
          <p>
            Director
          </p>
          <p>
            Ensure quality and timely delivery through resource and time management.
          </p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2 toggle_button">
          <a class="menu-toggle" href="#">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-down"></span>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <div class="tile">
            <div class="col-sm-2 img_tile">
              <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x50">
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-8 empDetails">
              <h4>
                Sen
              </h4>
              <p>
                Manager
              </p>
              <p>
                Ensure quality and timely delivery through resource and time management.
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div class="tile">Another Sen</div>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <div class="tile">Sen jr</div>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="tile">Justin</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Most of the code is posted above. I have some nested UL Li tags but can't find a way to create a logic that collapses or shows the list of objects around the click each time.

Comment: `$('this')` change to `$(this)`.. include all relevant code in the OP itself not in an external link

Comment: Thanks for catching that. Updated it. still no bueno.

Comment: can you state what you want and what is happening

Comment: added more comments and picture. does that help?

Comment: which ul should get toggled when you click the arrow it is not clear even with image

Comment: fiddle updated. that should help you. markup listed in sequential order ...

Comment: update the snippet still i dont which ul to toggle

Comment: forget about it man. Ill do this another way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A number of things are going on here.

1. jQuery is not included in your fiddle. Inside the Javascript panel, click the "gears" icon and select a jQuery version.
2. As was already pointed out, use $(this) not $('this') because if you use quotes, then you're passing jQuery a String of "this" instead of an actual DOM element.
3. In your CSS, you're setting all <ul> to be display none. You need to change that from `.chartArea ul { display: none; }` to `.chartArea ul li ul {display: none; }` so that only the <ul> *inside* the <li> is hidden.

I would actually recommend you change your HMTL markup a bit to make the DOM navigation easier, but to do this with your markup, you need can do the following things:

1. Identify the Parent Element that is common to both the <a> and the <ul> you are trying to show. In this case, it's the <li>, so we'll go UP the tree to that.
2. From here, we'll look down the tree for the <ul> that is hidden that we want to show. Since there's only one, it's easy to find it. Go down the tree to this
3. Now just use a jQuery method to show this element.

Here's the Fiddle. Note that I changed your jQuery and the one CSS rule.
https://jsfiddle.net/f4m22hmy/1/

Comment: Thanks TJ! one question about the fiddle you have- how do you avoid the grand child object sen jr from showing in first click and only show child? 
You bring up an important point- HTML markup change. I have been debating this for a while with a few variations of building accordion style that Im looking for with parent child relationship. Your thoughts on best way to setup the markup? I will have up to four levels of nesting. UL LI markup after putting everything (at least mine) looks fugly lol Surely there's a better way?

Comment: perhaps style on li or ul tag is better than the div nesting I have? creating a tile like visual was the reason I set it up this way...

Comment: Here's a quick fiddle on showing a list of items with one click. Do you want to just the items one at a time instead?
https://jsfiddle.net/f4m22hmy/3/

Comment: Thanks, TJ. Damn you fiddle fast. Appreciate it. What I'm looking for is accordion for the entire tile. kind of like org chart. If Amy reports to Joey, then Amy will be hidden by default but on click it will show. This fiddle I was working on might give u a good idea of what im after. that fiddle had to be tossed as I couldn't get past the logic of collecting a group of objects to show nested behavior. https://jsfiddle.net/zigzag/atdz4sa8/

Comment: Try this one.
Basically, once you set it up once, you can just keep nesting and nesting as much as you want.
https://jsfiddle.net/f4m22hmy/4/

Comment: phack! That's it bro. Let me test this out for a few things and style it in a way but the hardest part is clear! You a freaking savior. EXACTLY WHAT I WANTED!